# Joining Two tables Based on Third Table (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

I'm trying to use three different tables to get a list of all McDonald's in the US, sorted by number of Burger Kings within 100 miles. For some reason, I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around this problem, and I'm wondering if anyone can offer any suggestions on how they might approach a problem like this?

I have a table of all McDonald's with their zip codes, a table of all zip codes with number of burger kings, and a table of all zip codes within 100 miles of each other. For example:

`Mcdonalds` table:

| NAME | zip |
| --- | --- |
| McDonalds Park Terrace | 11121 |
| McDonalds HWY 103 | 11412 |
| McDonalds Crestwood | 11121 |
| McDonalds Pendleton | 26566 |
| McDonalds Smithville | 67742 |
| McDonalds HWY 66 | 43351 |

`BKzips` table:

| zip | numberBKs |
| --- | --- |
| 11121 | 2 |
| 11412 | 0 |
| 26566 | 6 |
| 43351 | 0 |
| 67742 | 3 |
| ... | ... |

`zipproximity` table:

| zip1 | zip2 | distancebetween |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11121 | 11412 | 23.443 |
| 11121 | 26566 | 48.211 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 11412 | 11121 | 23.443 |

My desired end result is a table with a row for each mcdonalds, listing all zips within 100 mi of that mcdonalds and their total number of BKs. For example:

| McDonalds | zip | zipsWithBKs | totalBKs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| McDonalds Park Terrace | 11121 | 26566, 11412 | 6 |

I've been able to use inner joins to get a table with one row per zip with BKs:

```
SELECT McDonalds.NAME, BKzips.zip, BKzips.numberBKs
FROM zipproximity
    INNER JOIN McDonalds
        ON zipproximity.zip1 = McDonalds.zip
    INNER JOIN BKzips 
        ON zipproximity.zip2 = BKzips.zip
```

But I can't figure out how to get my desired result. Between not being experienced with SQL and working this problem for hours I'm pretty stuck. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly there, just a `GROUP BY` and some aggregation functions:

```sql
SELECT McDonalds.NAME, McDonalds.zip, GROUP_CONCAT(BKzips.zip, ', ') AS zipsWithBKs, SUM(BKzips.numberBKs) AS totalBKs
FROM zipproximity
    INNER JOIN McDonalds
        ON zipproximity.zip1 = McDonalds.zip
    INNER JOIN BKzips 
        ON zipproximity.zip2 = BKzips.zip
-- WHERE BKzips.numberBKs > 0   -- you probably want this also
GROUP BY McDonalds.NAME, McDonalds.zip;
```